# Removing square brackets while using spark explode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am flattening the below json loaded to Spark dataframe using the code mentioned in the code section

```
{
    "id":"B07H3MVTSN",
    "mid":4,
    "inner":{
      "type1":[{
          "cid":"B06XVVSLX8"
        },
        {
          "cid":"B06XJ2JZ2Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Code

```
df
.withColumn("cid", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(df.col("inner.type1")).as("cid"))
.drop("inner").show;
```

It produces below output

Output :

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
|   id     |mid           |         cid|
+----------+--------------+------------+
|B07H3MVTSN|             4|[B06XVVSLX8]|
|B07H3MVTSN|             4|[B06XJ2JZ2Z]|
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

The explode function is adding [] in each element of cid column. I only want the string inside the []. How do I remove the [] ?

If i try to print the schema it shows the column cid, is Struct.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cid: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I convert the value from struct to string, so that schema is

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

```
df
.withColumn("cid",explode($"inner.type1.cid"))
.drop("inner")
.show(false)
```

```
+----------+---+----------+
|id        |mid|cid       |
+----------+---+----------+
|B07H3MVTSN|4  |B06XVVSLX8|
|B07H3MVTSN|4  |B06XJ2JZ2Z|
+----------+---+----------+
```